# How can I redirect With Dynamic Query Parameters on sucesfful Login with Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-cognito, serverless

I am using Amazon Cognito hosted login for my web app.

I would like to redirect users to the original URL they came from.

Right now I am redirecting my users to a base URL without their original query parameters.

**https://example.com/Production/v2/order-status/**

I want to be able to redirect them back to this base URL, but with the specific query parameters that came in this.

The desired behavior is that a user goes to https://example.com/?Id=500Dp000001a5TwIAI and selects login, they should be able to be redirected back to https://example.com/?Id=500Dp000001a5TwIAI.

Below is the current error I see when I try to add a dynamic query parameter.

[image]

I think that the only query partner that gets "forwarded" with the redirect is one called "state" that I can serialize and put your actual query in there.

Below is documentation from AWS Congnito on End point Authorizations utilizing the state parameter:

```
https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&
client_id=ad398u21ijw3s9w3939&
redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/redirect_uri&
state=STATE&
scope=openid+profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
```

so I created my url and added

**state=Id=500Dp000001a5TwIAI**

This is very close to working, for some reason, the URL converts the "=" to "%3D" and doesn't add an "&"

I am looking for a way to have the URL convert to the below on successful login:

**&Id=500Dp000001a5TwIAI**